# unable to post data from react js to node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am following a mern stack tutorial and trying to send data to api from react js form which is:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { useState } from 'react'
import './share.css'

export default function Share() {

  const [username, setUsername]  = useState('')
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null)

  const handleSubmit = async(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    const newPost = {
      username: username
    }
    if(file){
      const data = new FormData()
      const fileName = file.name
      data.append('name', fileName)
      data.append('file', file)
      newPost.pic = fileName
      console.log(newPost)
      try{
        await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/upload', data)
      }catch(err){
        console.log(err)
      }
    }
    try{
      await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/post/post', newPost)
    }catch(err){
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
  return (
    <form className='share' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className='shareTop'>
            <span>M</span>
            <input className='shareInput' type='text' placeholder="What's happening?" onChange={(e)=>setUsername(e.target.value) } />
        </div>
        <div className='shareBottom'>
            <div className='bottomIcons'>
            <label htmlFor='file'>
              <i class="fa-solid fa-face-meh"></i>
              <input type='file' style={{display:"none"}} name='file' id='file' onChange={(e)=>setFile(e.target.files[0])} />
            </label>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-calendar"></i>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-notes"></i>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-bookmark"></i>
            </div>
            <button type='submit'>Tweet</button>
        </div>
    </form>
  )
}
```

and my index js (serve side) file is:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const helmet = require('helmet')
const morgan =  require('morgan')
const postRoute = require('./routes/posts')
const multer = require('multer')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(morgan('common'))
app.use(helmet())
app.use(express.static('uploads'))
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb){
        cb(null, './uploads')
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb){
        cb(null, req.body.name)
    }
})
const upload = multer({storage});

app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res)=>{
})
app.use('/post/', postRoute) 
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/twitter').then(()=>{
    console.log("Connected to Database")
})

app.listen(5000, ()=>{
    console.log('Listening')
})
```

and posts route is:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const Post = require('../models/Post')


router.post('/post', async(req, res)=>{
    const post = new Post({
        username: req.body.username,
        pic: req.body.pic
    })
    try{
        const newPost = await post.save()
        console.log("post has been saved")
        res.status(200).json("Post has been saved")
    }catch(err){
        res.status(500).json(err)
    }
})
router.put('/:id', async(req, res)=>{
    const post =await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {$set:req.body})
    res.status(200).json("Account has been updated")
})
router.get('/', async (req, res)=>{
    const posts = await Post.find()
    res.status(200).json(posts)
})
router.delete('/', async(req, res)=>{
    await Post.deleteMany()

})
module.exports = router
```

So the problem is that the file is being uploaded to backend but the data does not, after doing some research i realized that the second try and catch block where i am posting the content is not being called, just the first api where we upload file is being called, can someone tell me what am i doing?

Comment: Is there any error occurring?

Comment: What is the content of your PostRoute file ?

Comment: so i have added my posts file above can you please look at it now

Comment: and no there is no error occuring